# JavaScript import causing errors

Tags: javascript, import

I am trying to use a JavaScript library from github ( https://github.com/andrmoel/astronomy-bundle-js ). When I try to run any of the examples given by the author (like Time of Interest toi), I get the following error.

Firefox:

**Loading module from “http://localhost/andrtest/astronomy-bundle/time/” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”).**

Edge:

**Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.**

The problem lies with the import statement which is as follows (from one of the code examples given by the Author):**

```
import {createTimeOfInterest} from “./astronomy-bundle/time”;
```

As it turned out, the above error of disallowed MIME is mainly because the import statement does not mention any file in import path (this is what I have concluded after searching through Google and Stack Overflow, of course).
Then I tried the following import.

```
import createTimeOfInterest from './astronomy-bundle/time/createTimeOfInterest.js';
```

It doesn’t work either and following error is reported:

Edge:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module './astronomy-bundle/time/createTimeOfInterest.js' does not provide an export named 'default'.**

Firefox:

**Uncaught SyntaxError: ambiguous indirect export: default.
My directory structure is as follows:**

```
--andrtest  |---andtest.js
            |---test.html
            |astronomy-bundle/
                |---astronomicalObject
                |---cache
                |---contants
                |---coordinates
                |   -
                |   -
                |---time/
                    |---createTimeOfInterest.d.ts
                    |---createTimeOfInterest.js
                |   -------
```

My test.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <base href=".">
</head>
<body>

<h1 id="myid">
    The Andrmoel Astronomy Bundle
</h1>
<h2 id="andr"></h2>

<script src="andtest.js" type="module"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My andtest.js file:

```
import {createTimeOfInterest} from "./astronomy-bundle/time/";

// Create from time
const toi = createTimeOfInterest.fromTime(2017, 7, 2, 15, 30, 0);

let head = document.getElementById('andr');
head.innerHTML=toi.toString();
console.log(toi);
```

I am quite new to JavaScript (TypeScript) and know little about importing files/modules. I am using the latest WAMP server on Windows 10. I have tried to explain my problem as much as I could and I have tried all the solutions given here on Stack Overflow and elsewhere but in vain.
Can anyone help me sort this out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, the package/library (`astronomy-bundle`) was written in `Node.js` and so not usable in browsers which parse only plain JavaScript (ES6) etc. As suggested (@wongjn), I went on to compile it using the popular build systems.
But I was unable to use the `astronomy-bundle` after compiling it through `Webpack` as well as `Browserify`. I managed to compile it successfully using the two tools separately. There were no errors, crashes, or something similar but the compiled code did not work either, though I tried my level best.

The only option left was to do it by hand and which I did successfully (i.e., convert/compile it to `ES6` manually, thanks to my coding experience with Java, C#, php and others). The directory and file structure of the library remain the same except the code is now in ES6 format and runs on all modern browsers.
I did not rewrite everything. I just changed the way various files are accessed within the library. In other words, I worked on the `import` of files and `export` of functions and classes within files and other minor tweaks and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the packaged code for `astronomy-bundle`, it seems to be in [CommonJS format.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS). This implies that the library cannot be `import`ed as-is from the browser directly. Also implied by [the installation instructions](https://github.com/andrmoel/astronomy-bundle-js/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#installation), the library assumes you will be using it in a project via [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en). One could then continue to infer that one should use a JavaScript build system to compile to JavaScript that would be optimized for running in the browser. Popular build systems include [Vite](https://vitejs.dev/), [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/), [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/), etc.

Comment: I think you're absolutely right but it is a **daunting** task for me to compile this library to get JavaScript optimized for browsers. As per your suggestion, I have downloaded Webpack and now I'm following their instructions to get the hang of it but this is all too cryptic for me. Anyway, thanks a ton and let's keep our fingers crossed.

Comment: Since I am new these concepts, I would like to point out that the downloaded astronomy-bundle files also contain ```.js``` files in addition to ```.d.ts``` files. For example ```createTimeOfInterest.d.ts``` and ```createTimeOfInterest.js```. What are these JavaScript files? Are these compiled or need to be compiled further?

Comment: `createTimeOfInterest.d.ts` is a [Typescript type declaration file](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) for compatibility with projects written in [Typescript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/). `createTimeOfInterest.js` contains the JavaScript code that you (presumably) want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Why am I unable to use these ```.js``` files or in other words, why they are not working?

Comment: Consider checking you are including the library code in your project correctly. Consider checking you have followed the [installation instructions](https://github.com/andrmoel/astronomy-bundle-js/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file#installation), and that you `import`/`require` the appropriate library code correctly for your chosen Node.js-based build system.